# Webapp undeployment memory leak when using OkHttp, false alarm or not?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, okhttp

OkHttp internally creates threads for the connection pool and for some kind of watchdog. I've seen multiple people struggling with this when shutting down an application using this library. The authors itself do not seem willing to address it (https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2482, "marginal benefit"). Specifically, Tomcat complains about memory leaks, since threads are left behind. It looks like these are cleaned up *eventually*, sometimes after a fairly long delay. So, my question is: is there *actually* a memory leak because of this issue? Eventually the threads are going away, so this should mean that all of it can be garbage collected. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of those OkHttp authors that doesn't like Tomcat code unloading. We're shipping our own concurrency abstraction in the next minor release; [details here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5512). This might shorten the 60s delay between closing your last response and the last thread exiting.

You shouldn't do code unloading in modern programs. Tomcat came from an age where the JVM was the long-lived container; today that's Kubernetes or other cluster orchestration tech. Tomcat’s code unloading strategy forces you to jump through awkward management hoops. If you are fighting class loaders or security managers you are wasting time on a made up problem.

Comment: I'm sort of seeing why you're saying that after having spent a day on the problem. Apologies if my tone wasn't very friendly, I was of the opinion that unloading/cleaning up after yourself was "the right thing" to do. Currently, not so sure anymore ;) OkHttp does now properly unload after a while, but there was a host of other problematic libraries as well (security providers ...). Thanks for your response!